# Ruby equivalent of Python str[3:]

Tags: python, ruby, substring

Is there a Ruby equivalent of Python's method for getting a substring that ends at the end of the string, like `str[3:]`? It's not convenient to have to put in the length of the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass a range with last element = -1

```
str[3..-1]
```